# Response data pass on to another plugin from open-id connect in Kong API gateway

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, access-token, kong-plugin

I have been trying to find solution for one of the task in Kong API gateway.

APIs are already working fine using keycloak authorizaton but one of my requirement is to inject another authorization from microsoft and pass on extra header to upstream server with Bearer token Authorization returned by microsoft's token endpoint.

I am able to get token and call upstream in postman. To get token, I am using
https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token
with client_credentials flow.

I tried to use open-id connect plugin to call token endpoint however this plugin has really big configuration and I am not sure if I am sending soemthing wrong. When I get token from postman and pass it in request-transformer plugin as Authorization header to upstream, API works as expected.

I also tried to add oauth-2 plugin but couldn't find it under kong api route to add.

I was thinking of something similar to oauth-introspect plugin so that open-id can return access_token in a variable that I can pass to request-transformer plugin as a header for upstream url.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that I could not achieve the desired result using the default existing plugins but had to build the custom plugin to authorize and get a token to pass on the following request to upstream.